# Why my Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 Freeze and keep blinking CAPS lock button?

Tags: gnome, 15.04

I have Lenovo G50-70 and Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 installed on it.
Sometimes it freeze and caps lock button keep blinking.
what is problem? what solution for this?

I installed the property drivers which in additional drivers section.